# How to: Add/Remove Class on mouseOver/mouseOut - JQuery .hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass, removeclass, jquery-hover

Looking to change the border color on a box..

..when the user mouses over/out..

Here's the attempted code.. Needs Work!

JQuery:

```
<script>
$("result").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("result_hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("result_hover");
  }
);
</script>
```

CSS3:

```
<style>
  .result {
    height: 72px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .result_hover {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
  }
</style>
```

HTML5:

```
<div class="result">
  <div class="item">
    <div id="item1">
      <i class="icon"></i>&nbsp;##
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You forgot the `dot` of [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) of result class.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e27Dt/)**

```
$(".result").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("result_hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("result_hover");
  }
);
```

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) on [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2) event

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e27Dt/1/)**

```
 $(".result").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("result_hover");
 });
```

Answer (score 12):

You could just use: {in and out function callback}

```
$(".result").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("result_hover");
 });
```

For your example, better will be to use CSS pseudo class `:hover`: {no js/jquery needed}

```
.result {
    height: 72px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .result:hover {
    background-color: #000;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the dot  on the selector, and you can use toggleClass method on jquery:

```
$(".result").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("result_hover")      
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is missing a `.` and though you say you want to change the `border-color` - you're adding and removing a class that sets the `background-color`