# Jquery hover exit function not working

Tags: jquery, hover, exit

```
$("#ss3a").hover(function(){
      $(".linksa").toggleClass("linksa",false);
    },function(){
      $(".linksa").toggleClass("linksa",true);
});
```

linksa has a "visibilty:hidden" css roperty.

The first part works however the div dosen't become invisible again when I move the mouse out of the div.

I tried the same with mouseenter and mouseleave but it's still not working.

Comment: have a look on second demo http://stackoverflow.com/a/16821586/2341815

Comment: So? Did you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$("#ss3a").hover(function(){
      $(".linksa").fadeOut(); //or hide, slideUp etc...
    },function(){
      $(".linksa").fadeIn(); //or show, slideDown etc...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because you at first toggle '.linksa' as false, technically removing the class. When your mouse leaves, you use '.linksa' as your selector, which is unfindable because you removed it.

Instead, do it like this.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $("#ss3a").removeClass("linksa");
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        $("#ss3a").addClass("linksa");
    }
}, '#ss3a');
```