# return background color on default - javascript bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in bit of hurry. Would like to ask you just one simple thing.

I am doing a mouseover and mouseout funtions, however I would like to setup up that x button would go back to default (background color) on mouseout event.

right now i have:
 on mouseover:

```
.css({"background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"});
```

please let me know how should i do to go back on default when mouseout happens thank you.

Comment: Store the default color in a variable and set it on mouseout. But why using javascript for a :hover effect anyway? Why don't you do the background-color change in CSS? (with the pseudo class :hover?)

Comment: there are some flesk operations in back ground, it's easier to manipulate with id and do the operation with logic than manipulate within css... I found the solution with sotring default color anyway.:) thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna use javascript, you can use

```
$( "#button" ).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).css("background-color": "none");
});
```

or if you want to control onmouseover event with css hover

```
#button:hover{
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add/remove classes on hover and set the css attributes of those two classes (i.e. one is default the other is specialized).
This answer may be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16821586/4636715